# Soma de horas em PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou aprendendo PHP/SQL e estou fazendo um sistema de contabilização de horas trabalhadas do funcionário. A quantidade de horas trabalhadas na semana é reproduzida como um número flutuante na variável $horasSemanais no formato:

- 0.25 (referindo-se a 25 minutos por exemplo)

Porém quando vou registrar no banco de dados essa informação, para somar com o número atual das horas trabalhadas no mês, utilizo essa query SQL:

```
UPDATE tb_usuarios SET horasTrabalhadas = horasTrabalhadas + $horasSemanais WHERE id_funcionario = $id_funcionario
```

Porém por exemplo, se a coluna tipo decimal **horasTrabalhadas** possuir o valor de 11.40 (11h e 40 minutos), ao somar com o valor das horas dadas no exemplo, o resultado ultrapassará os 59 minutos e ficará:

- 11.65 (11h e 65 minutos)

Como eu faço para o PHP registrar no sistema um valor mais organizado e "correto" quando estamos trabalhando com horas? Tipo **12.05** para representar **12h e 5 minutos** no exemplo dado.

Comment: 0.25 horas na verdade corresponde a 15 minutos (60 vezes 0.25 é igual a 15). Então 25 minutos seria algo como 0.416666... horas, e trabalhar com dízimas periódicas é complicado e os arredondamentos podem causar erros ao se contabilizar os totais, por exemplo. Enfim, talvez seja melhor vc mudar o campo do MySQL para guardar o total de minutos trabalhados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu fiz uma solução que resolve o seu problema através da recursão.

```
$horasTrabalhadas = fixHour(11.40); // 11:40h
$horasSemanais = fixHour(0.25); // 25 minutos
$total = fixHour($horasTrabalhadas + $horasSemanais);

echo $total; // Saída: 12.05

function fixHour($num)
{
    $decimal = $num - floor($num); // A função floor arredonda o número para o próximo menor valor inteiro

    if ($decimal >= 0.60) {
        $num = ($num + 1) - 0.60;
        return fixHour($num); // Recursão
    }

    return $num;
}
```

Veja com mais detalhes a descrição da função [floor](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floor.php) na documentação do PHP.

> Não realizei os testes para todas as situações possíveis mas acredito que no seu caso irá funcionar perfeitamente. Caso queira testar com mais valores use o [ideone](http://ideone.com/ZnNdw6).